# How to make nginx to listen to server_name:port

Tags: nginx, config

In my nginx conf file, I have :

```
  listen       80;
    server_name  $hostname;
```

however if I do netstat I see that it is listening on 0.0.0.0:80

what I want to happen, is the nginx to listen to $hostname:80 , is there a way to configure it to do that?

I tried different settings with no success so far. Appreciate your help.

Comment: I don't think you can listen on a hostname but only over IPs.

Comment: @JaimeHablutzel [“An `address` may also be a _hostname_, for example: `listen localhost:8000;`.”](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen)

Answer (score 84):

The `server_name`<sup>[docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html)</sup> directive is used to identify virtual hosts, they're not used to set the binding.

`netstat` tells you that nginx listens on `0.0.0.0:80` which means that it will accept connections from any IP.

If you want to change the IP nginx binds on, you have to change the `listen`<sup>[docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen)</sup> rule.
So, if you want to set nginx to bind to `localhost`, you'd change that to:

```
listen 127.0.0.1:80;
```

In this way, requests that are not coming from localhost are discarded (they don't even hit nginx).

Comment: I would please like to ask what reason could be to give localhost as listen ip, i.e. don't we want that the requests will be received from the output world ?

Comment: Yes, that's the reason. For local development this is usually the case. On a remote server you could do something like that to prevent the "outside" word accessing the site, limiting the access to only those that have SSH access to the server, for example.

Comment: @sjas then please provide a correct, non-misleading answer. :) Or at least an informative comment! As-is, your comment is useless.

Comment: you have to combine the mentioned `listen IP:PORT;` statement and also set up two vhosts - for the ip itself blocking ip-based access (else you will have a ip-based access possible which might not be what you want) as well as set up another vhost containing the `server_name SUB.DOMAIN.TLD;` which you want to be pointed at being allowed. is this answer senior enough, @JakeRobb?

Comment: @ransh The other reason is when you are running as a user without root on linux. I.e. you run the process on a port >1000 and add a port mapping in the OS from the high port to the low one.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. In our case, we want our own authentication/authorization software to run on the local host, and only once authorized can the request be forwarded to nginx. So listening only for connections originated within the localhost is exactly what we need.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone does not want to do this for localhost or any other *internal* IP (which is the only thing you can do by changing the address of the `listen` directive), you can use `allow`/`deny` rules.

```
allow some.public.ip.here;
deny all;
```