# nginx reverse proxy alfresco

Tags: http, nginx, alfresco

I have alfresco installed on a server, I want to force alfresco to only serve 1 language (italian) so, since it normally reads the language wanted from the http header, i set up an nginx reverse proxy to change the header.

The proxy runs on the server and listens to connections on port 80 and redirects them to the port 8080 where the alfresc otomcat server is running.

This is my server code in the nginx conf file:

```
server {

    set $language 'it-IT';
    add_header Accept-Language $language;

    listen       80;
    server_name  alfresco

    access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   html;
        proxy_pass http://<serverip>:8080;
        proxy_set_header Accept-Language $language;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

Everything works nicely, now i wanted to substitue  with localhost (or 127.0.0.1), i thought that it should work since nginx is running on the same server as alfresco but it doesn't.

In particular, when i use  and type the ip in the address bad of another machine i will get redirected correctly to http:///share/page/ and the page will be in italian (as expected)

but when i try to put localhost or 127.0.0.1 i will get redirected to http://:8080/share/page/ and the page will have the language i have in my browser.

Does anyone have an idea as to why this happens?

Comment: It sounds like you're bypassing your proxy with 127.0.0.1. You need to check to make sure your proxy is listening on all interfaces. See this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13634574/how-to-make-nginx-to-listen-to-server-nameport for relevant info.